# typescript function is not returning the value but it is getting consoled

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am pretty new to typescript i have create the function that return the access token when i try consoling it was working fine but it not returing any value when i call from other function
Function that return's value

```
static generateToken = async (user: any, expires: any):Promise<string>
=> {
    try{
      const config: any = await configHelper.getConfigData();
      const conData: string = JSON.parse(config);
      const configdata = JSON.parse(conData);
      const payload = {
        sub: user.contactId,
        iat: moment().unix(),
        exp: expires.unix(),
        user: user,
      };
      console.log('token one',Jwt.sign(payload, configdata.jwt.secret))
      return Jwt.sign(payload, configdata.jwt.secret);
    }catch(err){
      console.log('Error',err)
      return "Error"
    }
      };
```

Function where we call i have tried putting await in all the possible places but still i gets pending but it is getting consoled

```
  static createToken = async (userDetails: any) => {
    const config: any = await configHelper.getConfigData();
    const conData: string = JSON.parse(config);
    const configdata = JSON.parse(conData);
    const accessTokenExpires = moment().add(
      configdata.jwt.accessExpirationMinutes,
      "minutes"
    );
    const accessToken = {
      token: this.generateToken(userDetails, accessTokenExpires),
      expires: accessTokenExpires.toDate(),
    };
    console.log('$$$$$$$$$$$$$$',accessToken)
    const refreshTokenExpires = moment().add(
      configdata.jwt.refreshExpirationMinutes,
      "minutes"
    );
    const refreshToken = {
      token: this.refreshTokenGenerate(userDetails, refreshTokenExpires),
      expires: refreshTokenExpires.toDate(),
    };
    return {
      accessToken,
      refreshToken,
    };
  };
```

Comment: If you don't pass `Jwt.sign` with callback, it act as synchronous. But `generateToken` is async function. You have to add `await ` where you call `generateToken` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`generateToken` is declared as `async`. Which means you must `await` when you call it.

```
const accessToken = {
  token: await this.generateToken(userDetails, accessTokenExpires),
  //     ^ added await here
  expires: accessTokenExpires.toDate(),
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any `await` at the actual `generateToken` call. You would need to await there for the code to wait for the promise to resolve.

```js
const accessToken = {
      token: await this.generateToken(userDetails, accessTokenExpires),
      expires: accessTokenExpires.toDate(),
};
```

I would suggest you understand [how async and await work](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp) instead of trying to randomly add "await in all possible places" as brute forcing your way like this will only slow you down and cause frustration.

In short,

> "async and await make promises easier to write"
> async makes a function return a Promise
> await makes a function wait for a Promise